# Pointer Variable (*) and Double Pointer (**) Usage With Classes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

```
int a=1;

int * b;

b = &a;

int **c=&b;
```

In Objective-C, the Pointer (*) variable is used for primitive data types as well with classes like NSString, NSError etc...

```
NSString *str = @"iOS"; // or NSString *str= [[NSString alloc] initWithString : @"iOS"];

NSArray *arr =[[NSArray alloc] init];
```

I have seen in Objective-C (NSError **) what is use of double pointer objects for classes in Objective-C?

Comment: its just a pointer to a pointer.   Its a C thing.  I guess the most common place you see it is an array of arrays.  So if you understand how pointer arithmetic works, like for looping through an array, then imagine doing that two deep :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "double pointer". If you call it a "double pointer", you are just getting yourself confused.

Write a function that should return two ints. You can't have two return values, so you write

```
void f (int* result1, int* result2)
{
    *result1 = 1;
    *result2 = 2;
}
```

Now write a function that should return two NSString*. That should make it obvious.